# Subtract two Lists in Kotlin using a custom equal function

Tags: list, data-structures, kotlin

I have two Lists and I want to get the List containing only the elements in the first list that are not in the second one. The problem is that I need to specify a custom `equal` when subtracting. Let's suppose I want to use one of the fields in the entries of the lists. Let's say the `id`.

I implemented it this way:

```
list1.filter { log -> list2.none { it.id == log.id } }
```

or

```
val projection = logEntries.map { it.id }
list1.filter { it.id !in projection }
```

Is there a better way to do it? Please take into account that I can't set a new `equal` method for the class.

Comment: Looks good to me, what do you mean exactly by "better"?

Comment: @m0skit0 I was expecting to find Kotlin native methods to do something like this, I mean to define an `equal` method to be used only when running the command.

Comment: I understand, like passing a lambda to `minus` for comparison. There's no such thing. Your case is not a common case, that is, usually you should use the class's `equals` for that, not your own `equals`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way you do it is ok, but when the lists become bigger you might want to do that:

You could make the process more efficient by turning your reference list (`list2`) to a set first.

```
val referenceIds = list2.distinctBy { it.id }.toSet()

list1.filterNot { it.id in referenceIds }
```

**Background:**

An `ArrayList` which you are most likely using has a time complexity of O(n) when you check if an element is contained. So, if the list gets bigger, it will take longer.

A `HashSet` on the other hand has a time complexity of O(1) when checking if an element is contained. So, if `list2` becomes bigger it won't get slower.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach?

```
fun main() {

    val list1 = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val list2 = listOf(2,3,4)

    println(list1.filterNotIn(list2))
}

fun <T> Collection<T>.filterNotIn(collection: Collection<T>): Collection<T> {
    val set = collection.toSet()
    return filterNot { set.contains(it) }
}
```

Output: `[0, 1, 5]`

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, there's no built-in way to do this.  (Probably not for any fundamental reason; just because no-one saw a need.)

However, you can easily add one yourself.  For example, here's your first suggestion, converted to extension function:

```
fun <T, R> Collection<T>.minus(elements: Collection<T>, selector: (T) -> R?)
    = filter{ t -> elements.none{ selector(it) == selector(t) } }
```

You could then call this in the same way that a built-in function would work:

```
list1.minus(list2){ it.id }
```

(There are probably more efficient implementations, but this illustrates the idea.)

Comment: Kotlin collections now has this inbuilt. We can simply do `list1 - list2`. Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html

Comment: @bh4r4th Please read the question: this is asking about subtracting collections **with a custom equality function**, which the stdlib still does not support.  Subtracting with the objects' natural equality has been in the stdlib for a long time.

Comment: Yup yup got it. Make sense.

Answer (score 0):

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html

```
fun main() {

    val list1 = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val list2 = listOf(2,3,4)
    println(list1.minus(list2))
    
}
```